# Difference Between If and Else If?

Tags: java, if-statement

I was wondering why you would use an `else if` statement, and not multiple `if` statements? For example, what's the difference between doing this:

```
if(i == 0) ...
else if(i == 1) ...
else if(i == 2) ...
```

And this:

```
if(i == 0) ...
if(i == 1) ...
if(i == 2) ...
```

They seem to do the exact same thing.

Comment: & mostly you would be using else if statements ...

Answer (score 79, accepted):

```
if(i == 0) ... //if i = 0 this will work and skip the following else-if statements
else if(i == 1) ...//if i not equal to 0 and if i = 1 this will work and skip the following else-if statement
else if(i == 2) ...// if i not equal to 0 or 1 and if i = 2 the statement will execute


if(i == 0) ...//if i = 0 this will work and check the following conditions also
if(i == 1) ...//regardless of the i == 0 check, this if condition is checked
if(i == 2) ...//regardless of the i == 0 and i == 1 check, this if condition is checked
```

Answer (score 18):

The difference is that if the first `if` is true, all of the other `else if`s won't be executed, even if they do evaluate to true. If they were individual `if`s, nevertheless, all of the `if`s will be executed if they evaluate to true.

Answer (score 10):

If you have used multiple `if` statements then if the condition is `true` all will be executed. If you have used `if` and `else if` combination only one will be executed where first comes the true value

```
// if condition true then all will be executed
if(condition) {
    System.out.println("First if executed");
}

if(condition) {
    System.out.println("Second if executed");
}

if(condition) {
    System.out.println("Third if executed");
}


// only one will be executed 

if(condition) {
   System.out.println("First if else executed");
}

else if(condition) {
   System.out.println("Second if else executed");
}

else if(condition) {
  System.out.println("Third if else executed");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For the first case: once an ***else if*** (or the first ***if***) succeeds, none of the remaining ***else ifs*** or ***elses*** will be tested. However in the second case every ***if*** will be tested even if all of them (or one of them) succeeds.

Answer (score 3):

`if` statements check for all multiple available `if` .
while `else if` check when `if` statements fails , `if` statement return true it will not check for `else if`.

so it is depend on scenario how your requirement is.

Answer (score 1):

The first example won't necessarily run 3 tests where the 2nd example will given no returns or gotos.

Answer (score 1):

In first case, as soon as an `if` or `else if` condition becomes true, all the "else if" are skipped / not checked.

In the second case, even if value of i is 0, all the following conditions are tested.

So you can infer that, if you are testing for the same variable - which can't have multiple values at a given time, the better option is to use the first approach as it will be optimum.

Answer (score 1):

No they are different.
execution will check in every if.
i.e.

```
if(true)
 executes
if(true)
  executes // no matter how many ifs you have
```

while with if and else if

```
if(true)
 executes
else if(true)
 // system doesn't checks for this once if gets true
```

in short only one of any else if ladder will get executed.

Comment: I did know they were different, just wasn't sure exactly what the difference was. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

See, if you want check all the condition like one, two, three... you second choice is fine, but in many cases you have check only one condition, so you have prevent other conditions not to execute, at that particular case you have to choose your first choice

Answer (score 1):

A possible answer would be this:

#### Case 1:

```java
if(i == 0)
{
    i++;
    System.out.println("%d", i);
}
else if(i == 1)
{
   System.out.println("HI!");
}
```

#### In this 1st case

the output would happen to be only

```java
1
```

#### Case 2:

```java
if(i == 0)
{
    i++;
    System.out.println("%d", i);
}
if(i == 1)
{
    System.out.println("HI!");
}
```

#### In this 2nd case

the output would happen to be

```java
1HI!
```

Answer (score 0):

if : executed only if "condition" is true

elif : executed only if "condition" was false and "other condition" is true