# Difference between chained if's and else if

Tags: c++

So I have a question that I now have had for a long time, what are the differences between using else if and chained if statements, don't they produce the same thing? For example take this basic example:

```cpp
short age {0};
std::cin >> age;

if(age > 18) cout << "You are an adult";
if(age < 18) cout << "YOu are a teen";
if(age == 0) cout << "YOu are born";
```

and

```cpp
short age {0};
std::cin >> age;

if(age > 18) cout << "You are an adult";
else if(age < 18) cout << "YOu are a teen";
else if(age == 0) cout << "YOu are born";
```

How do they differ?

Comment: Related (maybe dupe): [Performance difference of “if if” vs “if else if”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7970275/2602718)

Comment: Assuming the compiler doesn't optimize it away, the first executes an additional test that isn't needed when age is greater than 18.

Comment: @Fran I realized that's for return's, which is a little different (which is why I retracted my vote). I think this may be a better dupe target (despite being Java): https://stackoverflow.com/q/20259351/2602718

Comment: @scohe001 Reopened.

Comment: Oh I meant add the second link, @Fran. I agree this question shouldn't stay open (though I can't vote after retracting)

Comment: In what you called `chained if statements` every `if` will be checked, in `else if` variation once one `if` is statisfied all next `elses` will be skipped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your specific example they are the same (note: question edited; now they are not). Anyway consider something like:

### Example 1: Modifying variables

```
if (age > 18) age = 17; // executes
if (age < 18) ... // executes!
```

Now you can see this would behave differently than

```
age = 19;
if (age > 18) age = 17; // executes
else if (age < 18) ... // skipped!
```

### Example 2: Overlapping conditions

Or as @cubic mentions, if the conditions overlap, there will also be a difference.

```
age = 20;
if (age > 19) ...; // executes
if (age > 17) ...; // executes!
```

versus:

```
age = 20;
if (age > 19) ...; // executes
else if (age > 17) ...; // skipped!
```

Comment: Not that the body of the first `if` has to modify anything, the conditions may overlap to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

if you use the chained if statements. the all if statement will be executed.
but if you use if else-if then it will execute only the true statement

e.g.

```
age = 10
if(age > 18) cout << "you are an adult"
if(age < 18 && age > 11) cout << "your are not an adult"
if(age < 11 ) cout << "you are a child"
```

in this case all three if statements will run

but in other case

```
age = 12
if(age > 18) cout << "you are an adult"
else if(age < 18 && age > 10) cout << "your are not an adult"
else if(age < 10 ) cout << "you are a child"
```

only first if will check and then the second else if(age < 18 && age > 10)
it will not check the last condition because it found the condition he want.

Comment: Right statement, bad example.. From your example I can't see how does it help.